# Enable rmarkdown / pandoc-citeproc citations in Jekyll blog via servr

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm basing my `rmarkdown`-Jekyll-Blog off of Yihui's [fantastic boilerplate](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll) for using [`servr::jekyll()`](https://github.com/yihui/servr), which in turn wraps `knitr`.

Everything's dandy, except I can't get `rmarkdown`-citations to work (which in turn just wrap `pandoc-citeproc`, I believe).

So when I add some `bibliography.bib`

```
  @Manual{Yihui-2015,
    title = {knitr: A General-Purpose Package for Dynamic Report
  Generation in R},
    author = {Yihui Xie},
    year = {2015},
    note = {R package version 1.11},
    url = {http://yihui.name/knitr/},
  }
```

to the directory, amend the preamble of the boilerplate `2014-09-28-jekyll-with-knitr.Rmd` with `bibliography: ../bibliography.bib` or `bibliography: bibliography.bib` (see below) and add this to the boilerplate itself:

```
## Citations

Work like this: [@Yihui-2015]
See the references at the very bottom.
```

This is what I get:

[[image: no citation working[1]]

Just to confirm that my setup is, in fact, correct, I ran

```
library(rmarkdown)
render(input = "_source/2014-09-28-jekyll-with-knitr.Rmd")
```

which produces an HTML *with* citations, as expected:

[[image: rendered[2]]

In a way, this is not surprising, because according to the boilerplate

> R Markdown source files are re-compiled through knitr when their corresponding Markdown output files become older1 than source files;

**So `servr::jekyll` currently runs files through `knitr` which does not deal with citations, and not `rmarkdown::render`, which does.**

How can I get this to work and/or would that be a worthwhile addition to `servr`?

Ps.: `rmarkdown::render`, all other things equal, is executed in its own R session (right?), with the working directory being *the directory of the rendered file*, so you need `../bibliography.bib` for it to work.
You would think that `servr::jekyll` *which runs from the root* of the blog directory would use that as a working directory in its R session and can hence find `bibliography.bib`.
I could be wrong.
Anyway, this is detail, and not at the heart of the problem here.

Comment: That is what I mentioned at the end: http://yihui.name/knitr-jekyll/2014/09/jekyll-with-knitr.html If you want to use Pandoc, you have to hack it by yourself. I didn't have a good solution. `servr::jekyll()` only compiles .Rmd to .md, and it is up to you or Jekyll on how to render .md to .html.

Comment: sorry, my question must have been unclear; I was really just looking (I think) for `rmdv2()`, because that calls `rmarkdown::render` behind the curtains. Should have read the manual *to the end*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had not read the manual carefully enough:

`rmdv2()` instead of `jekyll()` is the answer to my question.

From the manual:

> The functions rmdv1() and rmdv2() are similar to jekyll(), and the only difference is the way to compile R Markdown documents: rmdv1() uses the markdown package (a.k.a R Markdown v1) via knit2html(), and rmdv2() calls render() in the rmarkdown package (a.k.a R Markdown v2).

Because `pandoc`-style citations are introduce in R Markdown v2, I need `rmdv2()`.

Comment: Hope I got this right.
Oddly, though, `rmdv2()` *does not yield* any ready website, but `jekyll()` does -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122206/servrjekyll-yields-ready-website-servrrmdv2-does-not