# servr::jekyll() yields ready website, servr:rmdv2() does not

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, r-markdown

I'm basing my `rmarkdown`-Jekyll-Blog off of Yihui's [fantastic boilerplate](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll) for using [`servr::jekyll()`](https://github.com/yihui/servr), which in turn wraps `knitr`.

Because I want to use citations (via `pandoc-citeproc`, wrapped by `rmarkdown`) I need to use `rmarkdown::render`, not `knitr` to, well, render the `*.md`s.

As per the `servr` manual, I understand that `rmdv2()` should do the job, which essentially wraps/modifies `jekyll()`:

> The functions rmdv1() and rmdv2() are similar to jekyll(), and the only difference is the way to compile R Markdown documents: rmdv1() uses the markdown package (a.k.a R Markdown v1) via knit2html(), and rmdv2() calls render() in the rmarkdown package (a.k.a R Markdown v2).

Problem is:

`jekyll()` produces a nice website, here in the RStudio preview:

[image: jekyll]

`rmdv2()`, however, on the exact same setup, **does not work** but yields:

[image: rmdv2]

I also checked that the rmarkdown file in question was ok, by rendering it through `rmarkdown::render`, and it looked ok as HTML:

[image: HTML]

What am I doing wrong?